# Intermediate certificate and root certificate with two-way SSL?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, client-certificates, two-way-binding

I've been sent two server .crt certificates to use on my side for two-way SSL. I have a certificate that the server I'm trying to connect to has sent me for use too. I'm building a client api that talks to another web service XML api that uses two-way SSL. How would implementing that differ from just one server crt certificate?

Comment: *...I have a certificate that the server I'm trying to connect to has sent me for use too...* Doesn't make sense to me, the server doesn't send you a certificate for you to use to authenticate the client. Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: What I meant was, a certificate that the owners of the server sent me after having ordering it for the company I work for.